# Why don't we define algebraic variety by an atlas of charts with polynomials transition maps?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

The question is in the title but I will give details.

**Origin of this question:** I ask myself this question because I'm trying to legitimate the definition of algebraic variety (and then I would be able to legitimate schemes: it is just a simple generalization since point of an algebraic variety over a algebraically closed field are in bijection with maximal ideal).

I recall you for what follow that category of manifold define by an atlas (say $\mathcal{C}^{k}$-manifold but it work for analytic manifold and topological to) is equivalent to the category of ringed space that are locally isomorphic to the ring space of the $\mathcal{C}^{k}$ function of an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (if we consider for example real manifold). See here for a rigorous statement and proof of this result [https://pub.math.leidenuniv.nl/~edixhovensj/teaching/2010-2011/tag/sunil1.pdf](https://pub.math.leidenuniv.nl/%7Eedixhovensj/teaching/2010-2011/tag/sunil1.pdf) .

**What is my question:** For me definition of (topological,$\mathcal{C}^{k}$,analytic) variety by an atlas of charts is more intuitive, more natural than the one using sheaves (even if sheaves are better to work with). So I'm asking:

1. Why have I never heard about algebraic variety define by an atlas of charts (where the charts are homeomorphic to classical open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, not Zariski) with polynomial transition maps (instead of $\mathcal{C}^{k}$ or analytic transition maps)? If it exists does someone know a reference?
2. Since the "good definition" of algebraic variety involve Zariski topology, that means the objects of my question 1 above (i.e. topological spaces endowed with polynomials atlas) are not satisfying.. But in what sense? I think it is because the relation with sheaves is not true in that case but does anyone understand why (if I'm correct)? An example will be be great!

In conclusion I'm just trying to understand why the "naïve definition" of algebraic variety, similar to the definition of the over kind of variety is not satisfying and why we HAVE TO consider Zariski topology.

EDIT: I could (and maybe I should) have asked the same question but with rational transition maps instead of polynomial.

Comment: See [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275601/manifolds-with-polynomial-transition-maps) for manifolds with polynomial transition maps (your title).

Comment: Thank you @DietrichBurde, it is indeed an answer for my first question. It also remind me that I forget to include rational transition maps in my question!

Comment: I think that the main reason is that not all varieties of the same dimension are locally isomorphic, and a lot of algebraic varieties cannot be parametrised (only rational varieties admit parametrisations)

Comment: the inverse of a polynomial is not a polynomial, no ?

Comment: Something which isn't quite addressed by previous comments, I think, is that algebraic geometry should work on all kinds of fields -- but how would an atlas-based definition work for finite fields or function fields?

Comment: @Amr exactly as for homeomorphism we can ask in this situation that a mapping is an isomorphism if the inverse mapping is also a polynomial (or a rational function). But maybe there not a lot of such a function.. Otherwise for the Zariski topology non-trivial isomorphism of that kind exists.

Comment: @MarsaultChabat There are few polynomials or rational functions that have polynomial or rational inverses. In dimension 1, I think Möbius transformations are the only rational functions with rational inverses.

Comment: Another problem is that varieties, even classically, are permitted to be singular. For example, $y^2 = x^3 + x^2$. No neighbourhood of the singular point is going to have a smooth model!